# Should lost+found directories always be owned by root?

Tags: filesystems, lost-found

I'm using a script that creates file systems for specific users. One of the last operations of the script is a `chown -R` of the mount point to the user. This has the side effect to make the user the owner of the `lost+found` directory. Is this a problem? I suppose `fsck` will be able to use the directory anyway but this could have other issues (access to recovered files, etc...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fsck` can use the directory, it doesn’t appear to care about its ownership (at least, `e2fsck` doesn’t...). (In case it’s not obvious, `fsck` operates on file systems directly, so the operating system’s controls on file access don’t apply. All `fsck` needs is to be able to read and write to the device or file containing the file system.)

As you surmise the owner of the directory can at least view its content’s metadata (not that this is all that useful since the names are lost); the traditional root ownership of `lost+found` ensures that only system administrators can see what files are in there, and delete files from `lost+found`. Files which are linked into `lost+found` preserve their own ownership and permissions, so their contents are protected as appropriate. Furthermore since these  are user-specific file systems, presumably they have access to all their contents anyway, so exposing file metadata in `lost+found` doesn’t change the security profile of the system.

Comment: is there any issue if a user put some files into this folder since a user now has access to it?

Answer (score 0):

The only user who really needs access to the `lost+found` directory is the user that runs `fsck`.  Since that's usually done with root permissions, it shouldn't really make a difference if ownership is changed to a non-root user.

Probably the only thing it will change is that the non-root user will be able to read and write in the `lost+found` directory. This is normally restricted to users with elevated privileges.  However, I don't know whether files will inherit permissions from the directory such that a non-root user will be able to read any files created by a `fsck` process running as root that are deposited in that directory.

Comment: The user running `fsck` doesn’t even need access to `lost+found`, only to the device owning the file system.

Comment: interesting.  I didn't know it was device level access only required.